# Index design for queries using 2 ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am trying to find out how to design the indexes for my data when my query is using ranges for 2 fields.

```
expenses_tbl:
idx        date     category      amount
auto-inc   INT       TINYINT      DECIMAL(7,2)
PK
```

The column category defines the type of expense. Like, entertainment, clothes, education, etc. The other columns are obvious.

One of my query on this table is to find all those instances where for a given date range, the expense has been more than $50. This query will look like:

```
SELECT date, category, amount 
FROM expenses_tbl
WHERE date > 120101 AND date < 120811 
      AND amount > 50.00;
```

How do I design the index/secondary index on this table for this particular query.

Assumption: The table is very large (It's not currently, but that gives me a scope to learn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple more points that have not been mentioned yet:

The order of the columns in the index can make a difference. You may want to try both of these indexes:

```
(date, amount)
(amount, date)
```

Which to pick? Generally you want the most *selective* condition be the first column in the index.

- If your date ranges are large but few expenses are over $50 then you want `amount` first in the index.
- If you have narrow date ranges and most of the expenses are over $50 then you should put `date` first.
- If both indexes are present then MySQL will choose the index with the lowest estimated cost.

You can try adding both indexes and then look at the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see which index MySQL chooses for your query.

---

You may also want to consider a *covering* index. By including the column `category` in the index (as the last column) it means that all the data required for your query is available in the index, so MySQL does not need to look at the base table at all to get the results for your query.

Comment: I have been thinking that I will require multiple covering indexes. For a query like 'SELECT date, category, amount FROM expenses_tbl WHERE date > 120101 AND category == 1', I will require the covering index (category, date, amount). Now, for the query mentioned in my question, I will probably require to enable index merge. Just a thought.

Comment: @Ethan: Adding multiple indexes on the same columns in different orders can make sense in some situations. However remember that indexes have a cost - every index you add means that modifications to your table will take longer. For each index you should consider the benefit for reads versus the cost for writes.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL generally doesn't support ranges on multiple parts of a compound index.  Either it will use the index for the date, or an index for the amount, but not both.  It might do an index merge if you had two indexes, one on each, but I'm not sure.

I'd check the `EXPLAIN` before and after adding these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX date_idx ON expenses_tbl (date);
CREATE INDEX amount_idx ON expenses_tbl (amount);
```

Compound index ranges - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/range-access-multi-part.html

Index Merge - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks for the notes and links. I will check them up.

Comment: @JoshuaMartell . . . Thanks for the links.  I didn't realize that mysql does not use the index for the second key in a range.

Comment: It will if the first key is constant.  If you did `date IN (date1,date2,date3,date4) AND amount BETWEEN x AND y`, I think it would use both.

Comment: @JoshuaMartell: I tried the above indexes, but mysql is not performing  index merge for my query. I figured out that the compound index is beneficial for my query if I also include the 'category' in the index, as it then works as the covering index. From the compound index link you provided above, it shows that for BTREE indexes, once mysql finds a range request for a key, it stops using subsequent keys in the compound index (this is something you and Gordon mentioned in the above comment also).

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to your question is that you want a composite index, with two keys.  The first being date and the second being the amount.

Note that this index will work for queries with restrictions on the date or on the date and on the expense.  It will not work for queries with restrictions on the expense only.  If you have both types, you might want a second index on expense.

If the table is really, really large, then you might want to partition it by date and build indexes on expense within each partition.

Comment: Agree. Now, for queries with restrictions on both date and expenses, is there something better that I can do beyond the compound index (date, amount)?

Comment: @Ethan . . . the answer to your question is to partition the data by date and build an index on expense.  The expense index should be partitioned by date.

Comment: Just a clarification: you are saying about first partition on the table based on date and then on the partitioned tables another partition on the expense index based on date?

Comment: No.  A range partitioning scheme is generally only on one column.  It physically splits the table into multiple files, based on ranges of dates.  You can then build an index on expense.  A partition and index are two different things, but they interact the way you want for this.

Comment: Right. So effectively less data to work on for my query even when my table is large. Thanks.